# Custom tracking.borderColor in ZBarReaderView

Tags: iphone, colors

I have a custom iPhone-App what uses the barcode reader zbar.

My problem is the tracking border color what is green (my customers most hated color because its the competitors CI-color).

Is there any chance to programmatically change this color to f.e. red or blue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is already solved, the feature is available in the current sdk: http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/forums/forum/1072195/topic/4036084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is already solved.

With help from spadix (http://sourceforge.net/users/spadix/) this feature is added to the current SDK version.

More information here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/forums/forum/1072195/topic/4036084

Answer (score 2):

In the ZBar sdk, ZBarReaderView has a method called "TrackingColor". The default is green.
Here is the code to change the tracking color:

```
reader.trackingColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

I am using a TabBar. So here is the code I used to get it to work:

```
ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex: 0];
reader.readerDelegate = self;
reader.readerView.trackingColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

I hope this helps!